# mysql docker cannot connect from outside container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I've created a docker-compose file for PHP dev but I cannot connect to the DB with sequel pro neither from the APP.

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: laraveluser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

everything works OK and no errors are displayed but when I'm trying to connect to the DB in any way it doesn't work `docker-compose exec app PHP artisan migrate` nor with sequel Pro, what's wrong with my config?

The only way to access the DB is with `docker-compose exec db bash`

here the full [repo](https://github.com/sebalaini/laravel_docker-compose)

Comment: Please share you mysql dB container logs and the connection string you are using to connect to mysql.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal I've added the full repo, I'm using 127.0.0.1 root root in sequel pro to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

straight from the GitHub repo I have the answer, though I haven't tried yet as I think I'm going to stick with 5.7 for now.

You might need to add `--default-auth=mysql_native_password` to your command

Mysql:8 uses caching_sha2_password by default https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password

[#454 (comment)](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/454#issuecomment-406711790)

Answer (score 0):

After digging into your code, I found that you need to update  [.env.example](https://github.com/sebalaini/laravel_docker-compose/blob/master/.env.example) file

Replace `DB_HOST=db` on line 10.

You must have missed it,  but it is already mentioned in the [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose) that you had referred, under the heading **"Step 8 — Modifying Environment Settings and Running the Containers"**.

Comment: sorry the `.env` is not versioned, my local one is correct `DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=db DB_PORT=3306 DB_DATABASE=laravel DB_USERNAME=laraveluser DB_PASSWORD=root`

Comment: the `.env.example` is there just to be versioned and copy in your local

Comment: I created the entire setup using the git repo on my machine locally... went inside `app` container. Over there I found  `.env.example` with `DB_HOST:127.0.0.1` (Which I don't think should be there). Tell me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: the `.env` is used by Laravel to connect, you have to rename it or copy the `.env.example` in `.env` and change the `DB_HOST` to `DB_HOST=db` that is actually what I have on my local mac but that is not really a problem, start the docker-composer and try to connect to the db container with something like sequel pro, you will see that you can't and that it doesn't care about `.env` file

Comment: BTW sequel pro doesn't let you use `localhost` so you need to use `127.0.0.1` that is the same as `localhost`

Comment: I just tried the `mysql:5.7` image and everything works correctly, not sure what change with mysql version 8. you can use `127.0.0.1` on sequel pro and it will let you connect if you are runnig a 5.7 version but not if you are runnig version 8 that is the latest